# MSBuild: Build solution when only config change

Tags: c#, msbuild

In my solution, there are few XML config files. Now when there is the only config change (i.e. in XML files only), my solution does not build by the MSBuild & it says All files up to date.
This is obvious because there is no code change(i.e. in c# files) only config change. since the solution is not getting build it does not copy XML latest files into release folder.

NOTE: XML Config files will get copies to the output folder during the pre-build event.

Can someone please help me how to handle this scenario?

here is the screenshot of my pre-build event and property of xml file

[image]

Comment: What XML config files? How are the files being copied to the output directory (e.g. Build action setting)?

Comment: @mikez XML files getting copies during the pre-build event.

Comment: MSBuild doesn't try to figure out what you're doing with pre-build and post-build events for determining whether it should build the project again. You mention that your pre-build event is copying these files to the output directory - could you change the XML file properties *Copy to Output Directory* so MSBuild does the copying instead, and therefore takes that copying into account when determining whether it should build?

Comment: Are you building through Visual Studio? Or directly with MSBuild? In VS, just do a "Rebuild", if using MSBuild, you can do `msbuild <ProjectName> /t:rebuild`

Comment: MSBuild gives you a way to inform the engine of inputs and outputs to monitor for changes, but you'd have to write a custom target yourself in the proj file rather than using pre/post build scripts to do the copying. See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally) for more info. It may be easier just to remember to rebuild instead of build in this case.

Comment: @mikez yes you are right, it can be achieved by the separate target, let me try this.